# Roku ParseJSON gives Unknow Identifier error when loading json via AJAX

Tags: json, roku, brightscript

I'm trying to write a simple Roku application.

When I load the JSON file via `roURLTransfer` ParseJSON function gives me `BRIGHTSCRIPT: ERROR: ParseJSON: Unknown identifier`.

If I load the JSON file via `ReadAsciiFile("pkg:/feed/feed.json")` it works.

The JSON file is the same and I'm pretty sure that my JSON is correct.

```
url = "http://192.168.1.36/misc/roku/ifilm/feed.json"
result = ""
timeout = 10000

ut = CreateObject("roURLTransfer")
ut.SetPort(CreateObject("roMessagePort"))
ut.SetURL(url)
if ut.AsyncGetToString()
    event = wait(timeout, ut.GetPort())
    if type(event) = "roUrlEvent"
        result = event.GetString()
    elseif event = invalid
        ut.AsyncCancel()
    else
        print "roUrlTransfer::AsyncGetToString(): unknown event"
    end if
end if

' `print result` shows the correct lintable JSON
' print result
' Next line gives me: BRIGHTSCRIPT: ERROR: ParseJSON: Unknown identifier
json = ParseJSON(result)
```

But putting the JSON file inside the app works:

```
feed = ReadAsciiFile("pkg:/feed/feed.json")
sleep(2000)

json = ParseJson(feed)
```

I need to load the data from the Internet and using the embedded version doesn't help me. Does anyone know what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *"Unknown identifier"* error is usually because there's a character in the json string that `ParseJson()` does not support. The reason why `ReadAsciiFile()` works is likely because the function "cleans up" the json string by applying UTF-8 encoding.

A common character that's present at the beginning of some JSON responses that causes this issue is the unicode character [**Byte Order Mark (BOM)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

If you google *"byte order mark json"* you'll see lots of cases where this affects other platforms as well.

You can just do a simple find and replace to get rid of that character before attempting to parse the string.

```
bomChar = Chr(65279)
if result.left(len(bomChar)) = bomChar ' Check if the string has the BOM char prefix
    result = result.replace(bomChar, "")
end if
```

If that doesn't work, then your response may have some other conflicting character, in that case I would advise using [`ifUrlTransfer::AsyncGetToFile()`](https://developer.roku.com/en-ot/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifurltransfer.md#asyncgettofilefilename-as-string-as-boolean) instead of `AsyncGetToString()` and then use `ReadAsciiFile()` which should guarantee a properly formatted json string every time (as long as your json is valid).

Comment: Thank you for your answer; it was BOM. I'm having problem with Persian characters showing as squares in my application and thought to myself maybe using UTF-8 BOM might fix the issue, but no luck!

Comment: Np! The squares you are seeing is likely because of the font you’re using. Use Google’s Noto font: https://www.google.com/get/noto/